# Multiple Selects into one select

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to put some data together for a High Charts Bar chart using ASP.NET. Basically, i have three users who i need to track when they have logged into the system. the variants to be used are:

1) Today
2) This Week
3) Last Week
4) Last Month

So, i've created individual tsql scripts for today and and last week, but i'm now a little stuck on how to combine the two statemets, which will eventually be four.

```sql
SELECT Count(*) as CountToday from hitsTable WHERE Convert(date,hitDate) =  
Convert(date,GETDATE()) Group by UserId

SELECT count(*) as CountLatWeek from hitTable 
where hitDate between (DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF (week,0,GETDATE()),-1)) 
AND getDate() Group by UserId
```

Searhing on google, leads me to nested select statements, which all seem to form dependacies with the two statements. However, what i need to do is produce a table of results like this:

[image]

***EDIT***

I've set up a SQL Fiddle, so we can test out the examples

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a21ec

the fiddle has tsql for today and tsql for last week (which may need some tweaking)

Comment: can you use joins based on a common column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
Select Distinct
  UserId
, ( Select Count(*) as CountToday from hitsTable h2
    Where h2.UserId = h1.UserId 
      And Convert(date,hitDate) = Convert(date,GETDATE())
  ) As CountToday
, ( Select count(*) as CountLatWeek from hitsTable h2
    Where h2.UserId = h1.UserId 
      And hitDate Between DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, GetDate())-1)-7, GetDate())
                      And DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, GetDate()))-7, GetDate()) 
  ) As CountLastWeek
FROM hitsTable h1
```

Comment: Hi @asantaballa, thanks for the exmaple, this produces the following error:

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I would agree. From orig example, sounded like they were single results. You can work the Selects individually and make sure you get only one row with one volume. Then put them into the big select.

Comment: Yeah not possible unfortunately, as there is a row per person.

Comment: My bad, explained wrong. Should not have said only one row and can see where the initial exmple would cause problem. Try something like this (see edited answer). Selects the users from hitsTable, then subselects the counts for that specific user.

Comment: I've added a SQL Fiddle, so we can all see exactly what i'm trying to produce.

Comment: The SQL fiddle was a good idea. I think part of your problem was the date logic, not just the combing. See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select 
   id,
   sum(case when Convert(date,hitDate) = Convert(date,GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) as as CountToday,
   sum(hitDate between (DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF (week,0,GETDATE()),-1)) AND getDate() then 1 else 0 end)  as CountLatWeek,
   ......  -- Add more condition       
from 
   hitsTable 
group by 
   UserId
```

Edit

```
select 
  userid, 
  sum(case when Convert(date,hitDate) =  
Convert(date,GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) as cnt

from 
hitstable
group by userid
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a21ec/39)**

```
| USERID | CNT |
|--------|-----|
|  User1 |   3 |
|  User2 |   0 |
```

Comment: couple of typos in here Meherzad. Can you use the fiddle i've supplied

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another alternative based on @Avinash comment on the question.

```
Select 
  UserId
, CountTodayTable.CountToday
, CountLatWeekTable.CountLatWeek
, ...
FROM hitsTable h1
Inner Join 
( Select Count(*) as CountToday from hitsTable h2
  Where h2.UserId = h1.UserId 
    And Convert(date,hitDate) = Convert(date,GETDATE())
) CountTodayTable 
  On CountTodayTable.UserId = h1.UserId
Inner Join 
( Select count(*) as CountLatWeek from hitTable h2
  Where h2.UserId = h1.UserId 
    And hitDate between (DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF (week,0,GETDATE()),-1)) And getDate()
) CountLatWeekTable
  On CountLatWeekTable.UserId = h1.UserId
...
```